# jQuery.on callback parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

In the [documentation for `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), the parameters are given as follows:

> ```
> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
> ```

With regards to the `handler` parameter (i.e. the callback function):

> **handler**
>
> Type: `Function( Event eventObject [, Anything extraParameter ] [, ... ] )`
>
> A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value `false` is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does `return false`.

When are any `extraParameter` arguments passed to the callback function? There are a lot of aliases for `.on()` but I haven't come across any that pass more than the `eventObject` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example in the documentation:

```
$( "div" ).on( "click", function( event, person ) {
  alert( "Hello, " + person.name );
});

//You can trigger an event without user action
$( "div" ).trigger( "click", { name: "Jim" } );
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `.trigger` is defined as `.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )`, which makes the connection even more apparent.

Comment: Is this the only case where extra parameters would be present?

Comment: The only I could find are: `trigger`and `triggerHandler` which are very similar.

Answer (score 2):

> When are any extraParameter arguments passed to the callback function?

Utilizing [`.trigger(eventType [,extraParameters])`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

```js
var obj = $({})

obj.on("evt", function(e, a, b) {
  console.log(e, a * b)
});


obj.trigger("evt", [Math.random(), 100])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```